# Convergence problem when I try to integrate a function of one variable and one symbolic parameter

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have an integral with a parameter `a` and `a > 0`

```
Integrate[1/4*(1 - t^2)/(1 - t^2 + t^2/a^2), {t, -1, 1}]
```

I know for `0 < a < 1` and `a > 1` it yields different results, for `a > 1`, the result should be

```
a/(2 (a^2 - 1)^1.5)*(a*(a^2 - 1)^0.5 - ArcCosh[a])
```

But even if I specify assumption

```
Integrate[1/4*(1 - t^2)/(1 - t^2 + t^2/a^2), {t, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> a > 1]
```

I get a message saying, "Integral does not converge on {-1, 1}". However, if I input any specific number for `a`, the numerical result is correct. How xan I get the result as a function of `a`?

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem on my system, V10 running on OS X. When I evaluated your integral with the assumption `a > 1`, I get the result you were expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mathematica* V10

```
Integrate[1/4*(1 - t^2)/(1 - t^2 + t^2/a^2), {t, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> a > 1]
```

> [image: integral]

Comment: I am using V9. I found a V10 and it indeed worked well. I guess I should have an upgrade. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Mathematica v9:

```
mmaF[a_] := 
  Evaluate@Integrate[1/4*(1 - t^2)/(1 - t^2 + t^2/a^2), {t, -1, 1}, PrincipalValue -> True]
yourF[a_] := a/(2 (a^2 - 1)^1.5)*(a*(a^2 - 1)^0.5 - ArcCosh[a])

Quiet @ Chop@Table[mmaF[x] - yourF[x], {x, 1, 3, .1}]

(* {Indeterminate, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```